# how to make a list of template abstract class

Tags: c++, list, class, templates, abstract

I must to do a list of template abstract base classes (and I have the delivered classes too)
but I don't can inizialize the element of my list because the element is an abstract class...

this is my declaration:

```
/* fsm (list node) declaration */
template<class step_type> class fsm {
    protected:
        step_type   step;
        step_type   step_old;
        step_type   step_tmp;
        char        name[256];
        fsm *next;
        fsm *prev;
    public:
        fsm(step_type step);
        virtual void update() = 0;
        void show(){cout << step << ' ' << step_tmp << '\n'; };
        void init(step_type st_current) {step = st_current;};
//metodi per gestione nodo lista
        step_type getStep()     { return step; }
        fsm* getNext()          { return next; }
        fsm* getPrev()          { return prev; }

        void setStep(step_type s)   { step = s; }
        void setNext(fsm *n)        { next = n; }
        void setPrev(fsm *p)        { prev = p; }

};

/* fsm_List declaration */
template <class step_type>
class fsm_List
{
    fsm<step_type> *head, *tail;
    int size;

public:
    fsm_List();

    fsm<step_type>* getHead()    { return head; }
    fsm<step_type>* getTail()    { return tail; }
    int getSize()        { return size; }

    void insert(fsm<step_type> *n);    // add node to list
    void insert(step_type &value);        // new node and add in list
    fsm<step_type> *search(step_type &value);    //first node with value
    void delnode(fsm<step_type> *n);    // remove node
    int delvalue(step_type &value);        // remove all nodes

};
```

this is my delivered class:

```
class deri_pinza : public fsm<pin_steps>{
    private:
        bool    cmd_prelevamento_done;
    public:
        deri_pinza(): fsm<pin_steps>(ST_PIN_BOOT){
            cmd_prelevamento_done = false;
        };
        void update();
};
```

where:

```
enum pin_steps {
    ST_PIN_BOOT,
    ST_PIN_CHECK_MOTORE,
    ST_PIN_ZERO_MOTORE,
    ST_PIN_WAIT_ZERO_MOTORE,
    ST_PIN_OPEN,
    ST_PIN_READY,
};
```

I have tryed to test in my main, but it's wrong...

```
    fsm<pin_steps> *one, *two, *three, *four, *five;

    one = new fsm<pin_steps>(ST_PIN_CHECK_MOTORE);
    two = new fsm<pin_steps>(ST_PIN_ZERO_MOTORE);
    three = new fsm<pin_steps>(ST_PIN_WAIT_ZERO_MOTORE);
    four = new fsm<pin_steps>(ST_PIN_OPEN);
    five = new fsm<pin_steps>(ST_PIN_READY);


    fsm_List<pin_steps> *mylist = new fsm_List<pin_steps>();

    (*mylist)+=(*one);
    (*mylist)+=(*two);


    mylist->insert(one);
    mylist->insert(two);


    cout << *mylist << endl;
```

how can I inizialize the List without inizialize fsm ( abstract class)?

Comment: Why not use `std::list<fsm<step_type>*>` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 ... or even better with smart pointers (e.g. `std::list<std::unique_ptr<fsm<step_type> > >`)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ... or even better use raw pointers, but allocate the objects on stack and let them get destructed automatically when they go out of scope. (Unless they are needed out of scope)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Not sure it is the list which owns the object here...

Comment: @Jarod42 & user2079303 Depends all on the use case(s), but `std::shared_ptr<>` might be more appropriate, yes ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't create an instance of `fsm<>` with *new*, since it's abstract - it contains the pure virtual method `virtual void update()=0;`

you can for example:

```
fsm<pin_steps> *one...
one = new deri_pinza;
```

this is legal - and go on from here...

EDIT - followup to our comments:

if you need a more general deri pinza (a *generic* one), it can be defined as:

```
template <typename STEP_TYPE>
class deri_pinza_gen : public fsm<STEP_TYPE> {
private:
    bool cmd_prelevamento_done;
public:
    deri_pinza_gen(STEP_TYPE step) : fsm<STEP_TYPE>(step){
        cmd_prelevamento_done = false;
    };
    virtual void update();
    virtual ~deri_pinza_gen();
};
```

and then:

```
mylist->insert( new deri_pinza_gen<pin_steps>(ST_PIN_BOOT) );
mylist->insert( new deri_pinza_gen<pin_steps>(ST_PIN_CHECK_MOTORE) );

ANOTHER_list->insert( new deri_pinza_gen<ANOTHER_pin_steps>(ANTHER_enum_item) );
...
```

are valid insertions. I have declared update() virtual here, so you can derive your deri_pinza from this one, if you need it.

Comment: I've tryed with this instance,one = new deri_pinza; I've to link the step, e.g. one = new deri_pinza(ST_PIN_OPEN) all times?? for all stepS?

Comment: `deri_pinza` is the only concrete class in the example here, so it's the only one you can put in. If you want to put in the list something more general that `deri_pinza` you need a general concrete class... see edit to my answer (wait one minute! :) )

Comment: Buon divertimento!!! :) (attention - did a mistake, performed some edits to the post)